# ndarray functions won't compile in numba/JIT

Tags: python, sorting, jit, numba

***Update:**
As it seems, **.sort()** is **not** supported at all for **ndarrays** when using JIT?
With my ndarray given as below, I always get numba errors as soon as I have A.sort() anywhere in the function that should be jittet?
Is there really no way to get my ndarray sorted within a jittet function?*

I've been struggling for two days now how to get my code compiled by Numba/JIT (in I think it's called nopython-mode):

```
import numpy as np

Nmax=10000
T=50000
MyObject = np.dtype([('x','i4'),('y','i1'),('v','i1'),('vmax','i1'),('b','i1')])

for N in range(Nmax,100):
    A = np.zeros(N, dtype=MyObject)
    # Then A is filled with initial values
    # ...
    e,f,g=function(A,N)

@jit
def function(A,N):
    
    for t in range(T):
        Lane = np.array([(A[np.where(A['y']==0)]), (A[np.where(A['y']==1)])])
        Lane.sort(order='x')
        B = np.array(Lane['b'])
        V = np.array(Lane['v'])

        for n in range(N):
            # do some calculation here
            # ...
        
        A=Lane.flatten()
    
    return #...some calculated values for e,f,g
```

Without the @jit decorator, it's running fine, yielding all correct results so far, but literally 1000 (or even more) times slower than an earlier version using @jit. (normally a compiled run takes me 5-6 minutes, without @jit I've had it running for 12 hours now and not even 5% through)

I might go without the a.flatten() command, but especially if I cannot use ndarray.sort(), I would have to rethink my entire (now running) concept and almost start the whole project from scratch.

Comment: Use `@njit` or `@jit(nopython=True)`. It will give you some errors that you need to fix to make it properly JITted.

Comment: You don't need `.flatten`. Alternatives such as `.reshape(-1)` can be used instead.

Comment: `.sort` should be supported: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/461

Comment: Thanks for the advise regarding .reshape(-1)

About the error messages, the bad thing is that they are so deep in the compiler's structure that I do not really understand them, but I'm trying...

Comment: hm... .reshape(-1) still yields the same errors here.

Comment: Which errors? Please post the traceback.